# AT+CMGS="8080" return ERROR

Tags: sms, gsm, at-command, modem

I'm trying to send message through AT Commands in GSM Modem.
Normal numbers are working and sending successfully.
However when I try to send message to number `8080` it always return `ERROR`.

My command is

```
AT+CMGS="8080"<ENTER>
> BAL<CTRL+Z>
```

then it returns

```
ERROR
```

I already tried to send it using PDU and Text mode.
Also tried to save message using `AT+CMGW` then send it in command with `AT+CMSS` or send it directly using `AT+CMGS` but none of this are working with `8080`.

Any idea why its not working in this particular number?

By the way, `8080` is a network mobile number use to register or inquire promo in our country.

**EDIT**

It was working with Text mode. But why it is not working with PDU Mode?
Example for sending message bal to 8080.

```
AT+CMGF=0

AT+CMGS=13
>00110004A108080000FF03C22013
```

**More info**

As @Hans Passant pointed out.
Modem is working correctly, I already tried different sim card.
Keyword is also valid in the said sim card or network.

Comment: Can you enable error code reporting using AT+CMEE=1 to find out the error code?

Comment: Hi @manishg, It return `+CMS ERROR: 500`.

Comment: wow so error code is also not useful considering 500 means unknown error

Comment: Can you use the same SIM card in a mobile and try to send this SMS?

Comment: I try it, but it works with all valid numbers including 8080 number

Comment: Which modem are you using? What are the values of CMGF, CSCS and CSCA?

Comment: Here's the return: `at+cmgf=?+CMGF: (0,1)`, `at+cscs=?+CSCS: ("GSM","PCCP437","CUSTOM","HEX")`, `at+csca=?OK`

Comment: =? gives possible responses while ? returns the current response. I need the current response

Comment: Hi @manishg for some weird reason, it started to work using text mode, however using PDU mode does not work. any idea why it is not working in PDU Mode?

Comment: Can you paste the command and its parameters you are using in PDU mode?

Comment: Please see my edit.

Comment: Looks correct ! Can you try this? AT+CMGS=12
>00010303810808000003C22013

Comment: the command outputed ERROR

Comment: May be  you have to set correct SMS center number for your provider AT+CSCA = "8.....",129